# Trac not resync repository on first install of both

Tags: svn, nginx, trac

I finally get Trac running with FastCGI on Nginx (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFastCgi#SimpleNginxConfiguration). Also, Subversion was installed together with dependency package from souce download and I invoked svnserve as a daemon and created my repository. Everything seems fine.

I wanted to browser my repository in Trac. After I added respository into Trac from the Trac web interface  where it required a name and my repo directory. A message said:

> You should now run trac-admin $ENV repository resync "My Repo" to
>   synchronize Trac with the repository.

So I did. I did by user "trac" which is the same user that I created the Trac environment.

Then I got this:

**Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported version control system "svn": /usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra_neon-1.so.0: undefined symbol: xmlFreeParserCtxt). Look in the Trac log for more information.**

Here is what's in the log:

```
2012-06-03 18:28:51,060 Trac[svn_fs] INFO: Failed to load Subversion bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/svn_fs.py", line 267, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/versioncontrol/svn_fs.py", line 68, in _import_svn
  File "/usr/local/lib/svn-python/svn/fs.py", line 19, in ?
    from libsvn.fs import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/svn-python/libsvn/fs.py", line 7, in ?
    import _fs
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra_neon-1.so.0: undefined symbol: xmlFreeParserCtxt
```

Someone said that it's permisson issue that webserver and Trac are running by different user. But I don't know how to fix. Some said that it's the binding that I should reinstall. I tried go to python console and type 'import svn'. Nothing happened.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

What OS/version are you running?

Can you clarify exactly how you installed Subversion?  Did you download the source code and compile it from scratch, or did you install it via your system's package manager?

Similarly, did you install Trac manually or via package manager?

The last line in the error output is the troubling line.  The `libsvn_ra_neon` library (part of Subversion) is trying to reference a symbol that doesn't exist.  One thing that can cause this is incompatible versions of something trying to work with each other.  If you compiled any of your system components from scratch, try un-installing them and re-installing the version provided by your system's package manager instead.  That should resolve these types of problems by ensuring that compatible versions of any necessary auxiliary libraries are installed as well.

Comment: I installed svn from tar ball. The same version deps tar ball is included when I compile as instructed. It's version 1.6.18 all together with neon as sub-directory installed. There is no uninstall rule. Do I have to manually remove everything about svn to uninstall now?

Comment: I haven't looked at Subversion's makefiles in a while, but you should be able to read through the `make install` rule to see what the installation process did.  Going through the same process in reverse is probably the easiest (but probably still not easy) way to uninstall it.  In general, use your system's package manager to install things as much as possible.  It will automatically take care of most of this stuff for you, and it's extremely easy to run into problems when doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search reveals *xmlFreeParserCtxt* is part of *python-libxml2*.

This might help you to track down the inconstancy. But I agree to 'bta' that you should rather use a packaged version of *python-subversion* from the repository of your Linux distribution to get out of this quickly.